# Phoenix live view link not working with dynamic element

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I have code in an html.eex file that needs to render a series of links and I'm using this code currently,

```
<%= for item <- @links do %>
  <%= link(item, to: URI.parse(item))%>
<% end %>
```

However when this renders it just to an email it just puts it an  tag with no href attached like `<a> https://example.com </a>`

How do a I get the href portion setup correctly so the link can be clickable?

I am looking at https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Link.html#link/2 to base my code off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use standard

`<a class="tailwind for example" href={URI.parse(item)}>click me</a>`

tag or add class to your link which is missing from your example to become clickable.

`link("<hello>", to: "/world", class: "btn")` will generate
`#=> <a class="btn" href="/world">&lt;hello&gt;</a>`

the second is an example from the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Link.html#link/2).